# Databricks Delta table Alter column for decimal(10,0) to decimal(38,18) conversion not working

Tags: spark-streaming, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

In Databricks, the table is created using the schema json definition.

schema json used to create table

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "username",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "department",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "income",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "decimal(38,18)"
    }
    ],
    "type" :"struct"
}
```

Below code creates the table

```py
  ...
   # the schema json file is placed in a location and using it to create table
   with open('/dbfs/FileStore/my-schema/{0}.json'.format(tbl_name), 'r') as f:
          #  data files
          tbl_schema = T.StructType.fromJson(json.loads(f.read()))
          tbl_df = spark.createDataFrame([], tbl_schema)
          tbl_df.write.format("delta").save(tbl_path)
      # create table.
      spark.sql("CREATE TABLE {0} USING DELTA LOCATION '{1}'".format(tbl_name, tbl_path))
   ...
```

When i `describe` the table, i see DecimalType(10,0) for income field.

I am using readstreams to read data from ORC file, where the Decimal(38,18) is used, able to printScehma() in the dataframe.

I am using Spark structured streams write stream which uses UPSERT (merge into), using foreachBatch().

similar to the python example in this link https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/_static/notebooks/merge-in-streaming.html

Issue:

whenever i run the table is not inserted with the data. There is no debug log message as well.

I suppose the issue might be due to the field income being DecimalType(10,0) in the table, and dataframe with DecimalType(38,18).

So i am trying to Alter the field, but not able to do it. I am using below command.

```
%sql ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER income TYPE decimal(38,18);
```

```
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN is not supported for changing column 'income' with type 'DecimalType(10,0) (nullable = true)' to 'income' with type 'DecimalType(38,18) (nullable = true)'
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaErrors$.alterTableChangeColumnException(DeltaErrors.scala:478)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.AlterTableChangeColumnDeltaCommand.verifyColumnChange(alterDeltaTableCommands.scala:412)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.AlterTableChangeColumnDeltaCommand.$anonfun$run$15(alterDeltaTableCommands.scala:295)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.schema.SchemaUtils$.transform$1(SchemaUtils.scala:762)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.schema.SchemaUtils$.transformColumnsStructs(SchemaUtils.scala:781)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.AlterTableChangeColumnDeltaCommand.$anonfun$run$14(alterDeltaTableCommands.scala:292)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$5(DeltaLogging.scala:122
```

if i remove the TYPE , i get below exception

```
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'decimal' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 46)

== SQL ==
ALTER TABLE ahm_db.message_raw ALTER income decimal(38,18)
----------------------------------------------^^^

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:85)
    at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.$anonfun$parsePlan$1(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:67)
    at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.parse(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:87)
```

Comment: As a work around i used `dataframe.writestream.option('mergeSchema','true')`. Also in my case i was using `dataframe.writestream.option('mergeSchema','true').option('checkpointLocation',"/path/to/_checkpoint/')..`.  

Since i executed the ORC file from blob storage, and cleaned up few of the files. The checkpoint kept track of it in memory, and every time i execute the notebook it was trying to perform the previous operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the delta lake store in my case, had `options('checkpoint','/_checkpoint')` option enabled. The data reference was still available.

During development, after dropping the table and optimizing a using vaccum.

```
%sql delete from <my-table-name>
```

```py
spark.conf.set('spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled','false')
# use spark.conf.get('property') to check default or current value
# Per documentation setting retention duration less than 7 days is not a recommended practice, but depends on requirements
```

```
%sql
VACUUM <my-table-name> RETAIN 0 HOURS
```

```
%sql
drop table <my-table-name>
```

- Deleted the _checkpoint folder from the ADLS Gen2 storage account container.

After above steps, re-ran the json specific schema and it got applied.